# Sort a list based on a derived list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list; say, atom names

```
list1 = ['Ba', 'He', 'Al', 'Cu']
```

Now I have a derived list of, say, atomic mass of the atom types in `list1`

```
list2 = [atomic_mass(x) for x in list1]
```

Now `list2` is a float and I can sort in ascending (or descending order). How can I sort `list1` based on ascending sort of `list2` to get me something like

```
['He', 'Al', 'Cu', 'Ba']
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly was the result? Tip: you probably need a `key`.

Comment: Honestly I'm stumped on this question. I normally use `key=lambda val:val[n] ` to sort the list based on its own value. I have never encountered relating it to another list

Comment: Why can't you index into the other list? Or directly use the calculated `atomic_mass` to sort on?

Comment: I was assuming that you have `atom_name_to_mass` mapping somewhere. And you would use that to sort your list. I voted to close based on that. I am certainly not an expert in chemistry and if your `atomic_mass` function is more then a dictionary look up, then I will remove my close vote.

Comment: Its not exactly a dictionary lookup, but its close enough. Anyways, I used `sorted(list1, key=lambda x:atomic_mass(x))`  as described in the original question and it worked. So, it can stay closed

Comment: @WanderingMind note that you can just do `key=atomic_mass`, the `lambda` is redundant if it just passes through a single argument.